# Optional argument, by reference, for polymorphic method?

Tags: c++

I have a polymorphic method hierarchy like this:

```
void func(double x, const std::string& s) = 0;
```

and I want to pass an "optional" argument which is modified within the method:

```
void func(double x, const std::string& s, uint64_t& i = 0) = 0;
```

but I receive errors that my reference was not initialised.

What is the best way to implement the above?

Comment: void func(double x, const std::string& s = std::string(), uint64_t& i = 0) = 0;

Comment: Why does it have to be "by reference"? Can't you just pass by value? Then your default value would be fine.

Answer (score 5):

`uint64_t&` is an L-Value reference, and can therefore not bind to an R-Value, like the literal you provide as default argument. You must provide an L-Value as default.

One option is to define a dummy object that you pass as default, e.g.:

```
static uint64_t dummy_default_value = 0;
void func(double x, const std::string& s, uint64_t& i = dummy_default_value ) = 0;
```

Answer (score 5):

I would avoid default parameter for virtual method (see [good-practice-default-arguments-for-pure-virtual-method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139786/good-pratice-default-arguments-for-pure-virtual-method)), so just add an extra overload

```
virtual void func(double x, const std::string& s, uint64_t& i) = 0;
void func(double x, const std::string& s) { int i; func(x, s, i) };
```

If you really want to keep default argument, you may use `boost::optional`:

```
virtual void func(double x,
                  const std::string& s,
                  boost::optional<uint64_t&> i = boost::none) = 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use pointer instead of reference and within your function implementation only modify (dereferenced) value if pointer passed is not `nullptr`

```
void func(double x, const std::string& s, uint64_t* pi = nullptr) = 0;
```